# PropertyChanged event no longer work after deserialization

Tags: c#

I am using a class TrulyObservableCollection as listed below. I'm adding an event listener to the PropertyChanged event and that works fine initially. However as soon as I serialize and deserialize the collection and add my event listener then, the events no longer come through as can be seen from the unit test below. Can anyone explain why?

This is the class:

```
    [Serializable]
public class TrulyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [field:NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public TrulyObservableCollection() { init(); }

    private void init()
    {
        CollectionChanged += TrulyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void TrulyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems)
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems)
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e.PropertyName));
    }
}
```

Here is the unit test. SIEESerializer.Clone() does a binarize serialize and deserialize.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        TrulyObservableCollection<SomeData> tt = new TrulyObservableCollection<SomeData>();
        tt.Add(new SomeData());
        tt = SIEESerializer.Clone(tt) as TrulyObservableCollection<SomeData>;
        tt.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            string ttt = ""; // we never get here..
        };
        tt[0].Master = true;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SomeData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool master;
    public bool Master
    {
        get { return master; }
        set { master = value; SendPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you (de)serialize that instance? Some Serializers, like DataContractSerializer, create there instances usind `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()` that creates an instance without calling the constructor. In that case your Instance will not register the event handler. For that case the [IDeserializationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) is created that works for DataContractSerializer. Maybe that is a possible solution.

Comment: Also [OnDeserialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute can be used instead of `IDeserializationCallback`

Comment: do you attach to `TrulyObservableCollection<T>.PropertyChanged` after deserialization?

Comment: As you may see from the Unit test code, the observer is attached after de-serialization. That's what's so unexpected. (I'm using binary serialization.)

Comment: Yes you're registered at `PropertyChanged` but the constructor of `TrulyObservableCollection` calls `init()` that registers a private method at `CollectionChanged`. Normally serialization doesn't call any constructors. The created clone instance doesn't register to that event and that might be the reason why `PropertyChanged` won't be fired.

Comment: Thank you Vera, that's it. I've added the below method to the TrulyObservableCollection:

[OnDeserialized]

        private void onDeserialization(StreamingContext context)

        {

            init();

            foreach (T item in this)

                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;

        }